# How can I define a user agent in the URLDownloadToFile function for c++?

Tags: c++, c, file, url, download

I need to download a file for my C++ project, it normally downloads, but the URL that requires user agent does not download. How can I define my user agent in the `URLDownloadToFile` function?

Below Link is Example link only. A link that does not require a user agent.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")

int main()
{
    printf("URLDownloadToFile test function.\n");

    HRESULT res;

    res = URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Solid_blue.png", "C:\\test.png", 0 ,0);

    if (res == S_OK) {
        printf("Ok\n");
    }
    else if (res == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
        printf("Buffer length invalid, or insufficient memory\n");
    }
    else if (res == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) {
        printf("URL is invalid\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Other error: %d\n", res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser-ctl.narkive.com/mXAKey9f/urldownloadtofile-with-custom-http-headers

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly - I think you need help with creating a User Agent. Check if this link helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0713c39-89b5-4516-93fc-75f6aee696ee/set-referrer-or-user-agent-string-for-urldownloadtofile-with-ibindstatuscallback?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: okay i will try, thanks